# how to pass radio button value to filter data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL server to display some data in vb.net application. can I just edit my procedure? how to pass radio button value to display data based on selected radio button without changing VB code and without add new parameter in SQL, is it possible to do? these are my parameters.

```js
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LMS_Report]      
 @deptID varchar(10),     
 @month int,      
 @year int,      
 @startIndex int,      
 @pageSize int,      
 @generateData int, 
 @totalRecords int OUTPUT
```

sorry this is the first time I use vb.net

Comment: How would you expect to pass a new parameter without changing VB code?

Comment: because I can't recompile the code, I only have code from application after published, and I have to add this radio button into this report interface. could it possible if using substring to split @deptID parameters? I have no idea..

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the  steps

1)Get the value of radio button while clicking it and stored it in variable.

2)After that you can pass a values to stored procedure while execute a sqlcommand.

**for example**

1)value for radio button is 'red' this value is stored in the string "RadioButtonValue".

2)pass this RadioButtonValue to the SQL's stored procedure by using cmd.

**cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RadioButtonValue",RadioButtonValue)**.

@RadioButtonValue - variable declared in stored procedures.

else refer the following link

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Table-Valued-Parameters-to-Stored-Procedure-from-Code-Behind-using-ADONet-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I can think of 2 solutions for this:

1- using ajax, since you cannot change the code, you can update the .aspx files only and add AJAX call after the page loads to load your radio button, using the same procedure you mentioned before.. this solution is totally isolated as you don't need any changes on the vb.net code

2- Remove the `Inheritance` tag from the .aspx and add:

`<script runat="server>
rewrite the whole page code here
</script>`

You actually redoing the whole page in the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have my own solution:
1. split parameter which have varchar type such as bellow:

```js
Declare @condition varchar(20) = null 

SET @condition = SUBSTRING(RTRIM(@deptID), LEN(RTRIM(@deptID) + '|')-1,LEN(RTRIM(@deptID)))
SET @deptID = SUBSTRING(RTRIM(@deptID), 0, PATINDEX('%|%',RTRIM(@deptID)))
SET @deptID = RTRIM(@deptID)
```

2. get value of radio button from aspx page
3. add condition in stored procedure :

```js
IF(@condition='1')
  BEGIN 
  --your statement here
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
  --your statement here
  END
```

4. re-upload dll into IIS managemer